# OpenGL: color value at the edge of an object

Tags: c++, opengl

I implemented an application that simply renders a depth of a polygon mesh from camera view.

In vertex shader, gl_Position was set using simple code like below.

```
gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);
```

In fragment shader, color values returned are defined like below.

```
color = vec3(1-gl_FragCoord.z,1-gl_FragCoord.z,1-gl_FragCoord.z);
```

After render a single frame, pixel values were read as floats and saved as *.pgm image file.

```
float* pgmBuffer = new float[width*height * 3];
glReadPixels((GLint)0, (GLint)0,
                (GLint)width, (GLint)height,
                GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pgmBuffer);
WritePGM(width, height, pgmBuffer, imgname);
```

where WritePGM is implemented like below. target and source index equation is for the converting buffer order of glReadPixel result to PGM file format.
Also pixel value [0,1] is converted into [0,255].

```
void OpenGL_Render::WritePGM(int width, int height, float* buffer, char* outPGM)
{
    int* gbuffer = new int[width*height];
    unsigned char *cbuffer = new unsigned char[width*height*sizeof(unsigned char)];

    int line = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            int target = i*width + j;
            int source = width*height * 3 - (((i+1)*width - (j+1)) * 3);

            cbuffer[target] = buffer[source]*255;
        }

    }

    ofstream fout(outPGM);
    fout << "P5\n" << width << " " << height << "\n255\n";
    fout.write((char *)cbuffer, width*height * sizeof(unsigned char));
    fout.close();
}
```

**Here is the problem. When I opened up the result PGM image and observed pixel values, I found that at the edge of a polygon mesh, there are some pixel values between min and max of neighbors like you can see in below screenshots. In here I mean edge as a silhouette or contour of a polygon mesh.**

[image: Rendering result of a box]

[image: Pixel values observed at the edge]

**My questions are,**

1. I guess those intermediate values are generated from interpolator of GPU. Is it right? FYI, I didn't use any other fragment shader for instance, anit-aliasing.
2. If it is right, how can I remove or disable the interpolation?
3. If it is wrong, what is the cause of those intermediate values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess those intermediate values are generated from interpolator of
>   GPU. Is it right?

No. Interpolator in graphics pipeline is not about what you see on the edge. Let me explain what interpolation is usually used for. Your vertex/tess/geometry shader(s) eventually produce vertex data, i.e. they set position, normal and other values for each vertex. For example, a vertex shader is invoked only 3 times per triangle (for each vertex). But a fragment shader is completely another thing. It is invoked for each fragment of the primitive (for simplicity you may assume that fragment == pixel). Then, if I want to get a normal vector of a triangle for current fragment (point on the triangle), which one should I use? A triangle may have three different normal vectors! The answer is: neither of them. See, when you write `out` variable in vertex (as well as tesselation or geometry) shader, the corresponding `in` variable of the fragment shader gets a value interpolated from all per-vertex values of current primitive. This allows to produce the following effect:

[image: Phong shader with and without interpolation]

Pay attention at the edge of the right sphere. It has no more polygons than the left one, but it's smooth! This effect is possible because the normal in each vertex (the point where four quads touch each other) is a *true* normal of the sphere. It is actually not perpendicular to any of the surrounding quads, but it is, in fact, the radius-vector of the vertex, as it is supposed to be in mathematically correct sphere. But on the left picture the interpolation is turned off, and each quad is illuminated with only one normal (selected somehow) per quad, so all pixels of the same quad have the same normal, while on the right picture each pixel got it's own normal vector which was interpolated from the corners of the quad.

Applying the above to your screenshots, we see that interpolation only caused smooth gradients on the *faces* of your cube, but not edges. Without it you would get something like this:

[image: A cube without vertex color interpolation]

As a more primitive example, imagine you want to draw a line (for example, using GL_LINES) which smoothly changes it's color from black to white. But you only may set the color value for two points on the line: for it's beginning and for the end. Thus, if you have no interpolation, you'll get completely black or completely white line, depending on some other settings. For example, 11 pixel long line will look like this:

```
|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|
```

But with interpolation enabled, pixel colors will change smoothly:

```
|0.0|0.1|0.2|0.3|0.4|0.5|0.6|0.7|0.8|0.9|1.0|
```

Interpolation of vertex-to-fragment shader variables is enabled by default, but you may disable it with `flat` [interpolation qualifier](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers).

Now the second question.

> If it is wrong, what is the cause of those intermediate values?

The cause is that you have antialiasing enabled. You don't need any extra work or special shaders to get antialiased rendering until you don't use some advanced shading techniques. Here is a list of where enabled antialiasing may come from:

- You called `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);` somewhere in your code.
- Your window handling library has done it for you.
- Antialiasing is forced somewhere in your video driver options. As far as I remember, nVidia drivers for Windows had such a feature some time ago.

Comment: Thanks Sergey! Simply turning off the altialiasing options in nVidia driver solved this issue. I though that OpenGL API is "lower level" than the graphic card options...stupid.